# Почему вывод в Pysnmp отличается от вывода в терминале?

Tags: python, python-3.x, snmp

Помогите разобраться, данный код выводит множество значений Разных MIB`ов, хотя мне нужны значения только ifIndex

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *
for(errorIndication,
    errorStatus,
    errorIndex,
    varBinds) in bulkCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                CommunityData('community'),
                UdpTransportTarget(('ip', 161)),
                ContextData(),
                0,25,
                ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'ifNumber').addAsn1MibSource(
                        'file:///usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf'))):
    if errorIndication:
        print(errorIndication)
        break
    elif errorStatus:
        print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                            errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))
        break
    else:

        for varBind in varBinds:
            print(varBind)
```

в терминале же `snmpbulkwalk -On -v2c -c 'community' 'ip' Ifindex` выводит только  информацию по IfIndex.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ.
Необходимо было добавить:`lookupMib=True,
                lexicographicMode=False`

```
for(errorIndication,
errorStatus,
errorIndex,
varBinds) in bulkCmd(SnmpEngine(),
            CommunityData('zaBbIX-mON'),
            UdpTransportTarget(('192.168.57.8', 161)),
            ContextData(),
            0,25,
            ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'ifIndex').addAsn1MibSource(
                    'file:///usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf')),
            lookupMib=True,
            lexicographicMode=False
            ):
if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)
    break
elif errorStatus:
    print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                        errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))
    break
else:

    for varBind in varBinds:
        print(varBind)
```